# Css Increase the height of the div according to the font size

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm basically going to make an accessibility to increase the font size, but I'm not sure how to achieve this:
basically I need my div to increase in height when the size of my text passes the maximum width something like this:
[image]

at the moment if I try this I have this:

[image]

---

passes my maximum width and does not increase in height as a "line break" as in the previous gif
code:

```
<ContainerNav>
    <Content>
        <Nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#homex">home2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#homexv">home3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#homexv">home4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#homexv">home5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#homexv">home6</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </Nav>
    </Content>
</ContainerNav>
```

css:

```
 const flex = props => css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: ${props.flexdirection};
`;



const flexAlignCenter = css`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

 const mxw80 = css`
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80rem !important;
  width: 80rem !important;
`;

export const ContainerNav = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #8ac926;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(18, 23, 39, 0.4);
`;
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  height: auto;
  ${flexAlignCenter}
  & > ul {
    ${flexAlignCenter}
    max-width:500px;
    background: green;
    height: auto;
  }
  & > ul > li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: blue;
  }
  & > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
`;
export const Content = styled.div`
  ${mxw80}
  ${flex}
`;
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-murdock-1pdul

Comment: Its not working https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-murdock-1pdul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you only have to set the `heigth` of `ContainerNav` to `auto` instead of the fixed height of 50px.

Comment: yes i ended up forgetting to switch to auto, but from the same jetio i don't get the behavior of the gif, i need the read not to be in a single line when they are at maximum height and this is happening

Comment: basically if i increase the font size i would like them to respect my maximum width defined in my ul and then never go beyond that width and jump the line, I would like that when it reaches the maximum width it skips the line and doesn't stay on the same line and it doesn't happen.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but I think you should try to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` so the items will wrap when the content exceeds the maximum width of the container. Is it that what you mean? https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-shape-3f0u6